# A better word than "volunteer"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have developed a method of removing chronic pain and train people to be able to help others. When I train them I demonstrate on a "volunteer" member of the public. I also like to arrange one volunteer per trainee to work on at the end of the training. The thing is that it works with a 97% reduction of pain on average, so this isn't being a guinea pig or a test and when I promote it for free and ask for "volunteers" it doesn't get much response. I believe "volunteer" has a negative feel, like being asked to do something for no return.

Is there a better word I can use that suggests that it is a win-win situation, that they stand a very good chance of leaving pain-free and that the newly trained practitioner gets a lot out of working on their first client under supervision?

Comment: It would help to have an example sentence for context, but instead of saying something like  “pain reduction volunteers wanted” you could say “free pain reduction session with trainee practitioner” - that makes it clear what’s in it for them and what’s in it for you.

Comment: Volunteer is a normal word to use in these scenarios. It's possible you're not getting a response because the people you are speaking to are skeptical.

Comment: Participants wanted for free treatment samples.

Comment: The people you describe can be regarded as *receiving* something for free rather than *donating* their time. You just need to describe your invitation to participate in these terms. You could even call them **applicants** in order to suggest a service in demand. *We are now calling for applications to participate in the Laurel Program, offering potential relief from chronic pain, delivered free by our trainee practitioners. Applicants will be required to...*

Comment: @Orbital the OP found your **comment** useful, could you turn it into an answer, please?

Comment: Not _guinea pig_, then.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Yosef Baskin, these people can be seen as **participants** in a free treatment program (or at least an opportunity to sample that program). They are not merely volunteers as they are as *receiving* something for free rather than merely *donating* their time. I suggest you frame your invitation to participate in these terms, treating them as **applicants** in order to suggest a service in demand:

> We are now calling for applications to participate in the *Laurel Program*, offering potential relief from chronic pain, delivered free by our trainee practitioners. Applicants will be required to...